# Magento CMS - widgets in widgets

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, cms, widgets, cms-block

I have a problem with the magento cms. The perfect solution would be to have widgets nested in another widgets (similar approach like TYPO3 FCEs). I've got a lot of problems with escaping, editing and saving this deeply nested structure. Is there a better way to accomplish this? What I actually want is to create elements with a certain html frame with the possibility to insert another elements of the similar kind. You can think about it as of bootstrap elements, where I want something like row-element containing col-elements containing other elements. I know, that it can be done with static blocks, but the usability is quite poor.

Would appreciate any ideas or suggestions!

Comment: what about using static blocks with js ans css enabled. you can put any css rules for a static block and make out desired result. Checkout https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magento-js-css-for-static-blocks

Comment: @programmer_rkt for a developer it's not a problem at all, but you cannot give such low-level tool to a customer without having doubts that he will call you 5 minutes later an say that the whole layout is broken :-) And you still have a problem of nesting these blocks and having to switch the scope all the time until you have the structure you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this but if you have a widget that loads a static block you could add another widget in that static block again and so on. Basically having widget-ception.

It would, I guess, look something like this:

```
class[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Widget
   extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
      implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    protected $_serializer = null;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_serializer = new Varien_Object();
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * Produce links list rendered as html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $staticBlockId = $this->getData('static_block_id');

        return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($staticBlockId)->toHtml()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was my initial idea, too. But if you want to create a row with four columns and content inside them, you have to go back and forth between the page and cms blocks all the time. I would want to have something where you can ideally create and edit everything at once.